# integral of composition of functions

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I am supposed to find the things on which the sign of the following integral depends,
$\int_{0}^{t} p'(x)((q'(x))-3) dx$,

where $p(x)=f(g(x))\,\,\,\,\,\,\,q(x)=g(f(x)) $, where $f(x)$ is a strictly increasing function and $g(x)$ is a strictly decreasing function. Now I know that $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ both are strictly decreasing, but i think the sign of the integral will depend on functions $f(x),g(x)$ and the sign of the value  $t$. Am I missing something?

I couldn't come up with examples where the sign depends on functions still.

Comment: Your parentheses don't match (3 opening, 4 closing), so it's not clear what you're asking.

Comment: fixed it now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{dp}{dx}=\frac{df}{dg}\frac{dg}{dx}<0$$
$$\frac{dq}{dx}-3=\frac{dg}{df}\frac{df}{dx}-3<-3$$
So the anti derivative $H$ is strictly increasing and:
$$\int_0^t p'(x)(q'(x)-3)dx=H(t)-H(0)$$
Is positive for $t>0$, $0$ for $t=0$ and negative for $t<0$.